# How to add timezone with next auth max age?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I live in India and here the timezone is IST .

Sounds like the default time zone NextJS uses is UTC 0 because I defined the maxAge for the session as 1 hour but actually, the session expires 3 hours later.

How could I fix it ?

`session: { maxAge: 60 * 60, // 1 hour in seconds },`

Set the expiretime 1 hour from now